# How to get X-Page-Usage or the API usage limit using Facebook SDK?

Tags: php, facebook

I am in a project which I consult the Facebook API through Facebook PHP SDK, but I can't find my current call limit through SDK Facebook PHP. Is there any way to know the limit while making calls.

Comment: I don’t know if there’s any dedicated methods for that yet, but I’d start by looking at what FacebookResponse::getHeaders() returns.

Comment: thank you very much 04FS  were right, you save my day

Comment: Hello @EduardoXavierMorales Could you please let me know how you fixed that issue, i am facing the same issue right now, wanna know rate-limit but not getting any headers data from facebook_business library.

What i really meant to ask you is that how you are getting an object of FacebookResponse class?